# Flask Python Calculator 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, flask

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask import Flask, request

# create app
app = Flask(__name__)


def calculate(r,t,l):
    return ((l+t)/2)*3


def forecast(rem, sold1, sold2):


     if (rem == 0 and sold1 == 0 and sold2 ==0): #All ZERO
         result = 15
     elif (rem == 0 and sold1 == 0 and sold2 < 10): #ALL FOR ONE PRODUCT VALUE
         result = sold2*3
     elif (rem == 0 and sold1 < 10 and sold2 ==0):
         result = sold1*3
     elif (rem < 10 and sold1 == 0 and sold2 == 0):
         result = rem*3
     #END FOR ONE PRODUCT VALUE
     elif (rem>= 10 and  sold1>=10 and sold2>=10):

          if((rem/3)>=(sold1+10) or (rem/3)>=(sold1+10)):
              result = 0
          else:
              result = calculate(rem,sold1,sold2)-rem
     elif (rem<10 and sold1<10 and sold2<10):
         result = calculate(rem,sold1,sold2)
     elif (rem == 0 and sold1>=10 and sold2>=10):
         result = calculate(rem,sold1,sold2)
     else:
         result = sold1



     print ("\n\nSuggested stock purchase: ")


     return result


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # show html form
        return '''
            <form method="post">
                <input type="text" name="remaining" />
                <input type="text" name="sold1" />
                <input type="text" name="sold2" />

                <input type="submit" value="forecast" />
            </form>
        '''
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        # calculate result
        rem = request.form.get('remaining')
        sold1 = request.form.get('sold1')
        sold2 = request.form.get('sold2')

        result = forecast(rem,sold1,sold2)
        return 'result: %s' % result
```

I'm trying to make a python forecast calculator web app. and I can't find the error. I tried making this with the simple "eval" function and it works but when I make  my own function to calculate the received inputs it gets the error. How do I fix this?

Traceback:

```
2017-03-22 06:20:59,184 :[2017-03-22 06:20:59,182] ERROR in app: Exception on / [POST]

2017-03-22 06:20:59,186 :Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-03-22 06:20:59,186 :  File "/home/Firiyuu77/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
2017-03-22 06:20:59,186 :    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2017-03-22 06:20:59,187 :  File "/home/Firiyuu77/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
2017-03-22 06:20:59,187 :    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2017-03-22 06:20:59,187 :  File "/home/Firiyuu77/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
2017-03-22 06:20:59,187 :    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2017-03-22 06:20:59,188 :  File "/home/Firiyuu77/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
2017-03-22 06:20:59,188 :    rv = self.dispatch_request()
2017-03-22 06:20:59,188 :  File "/home/Firiyuu77/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
2017-03-22 06:20:59,188 :    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2017-03-22 06:20:59,188 :  File "/home/Firiyuu77/mysite/flask_app.py", line 64, in index
2017-03-22 06:20:59,188 :    result = forecast(rem,sold1,sold2)
2017-03-22 06:20:59,188 :  File "/home/Firiyuu77/mysite/flask_app.py", line 26, in forecast
2017-03-22 06:20:59,189 :    if((rem/3)>=(sold1+10) or (rem/3)>=(sold1+10)):
2017-03-22 06:20:59,189 :TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'unicode' and 'int'
```

Comment: post the traceback

Comment: I have just updated it @AvinashRaj Thanks!

Comment: convert `rem`, `sold1` to int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data type you got from form is not `int` but `unicode`, you can cast them to the type you need like `int` and then pass them to `forecast`:

```
result = forecast(int(rem),int(sold1),int(sold2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that flask gives you `str` for the `rem` var. all you need to do is to replace this line:
`rem = request.form.get('remaining')`

with this:

`rem = int(request.form.get('remaining'))`

You do this for your other vars too

Answer (score 0):

`rem = request.form.get('remaining')`

is a string, not an int.

You can convert it by

`rem = int(request.form.get('remaining'))`